# How to create a UITextField with n number of lines inside a UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

How to create a UITextField with n number of lines inside a UITableview.Each cell may contain 1 or more number of heights, So that UITableView will have different cell heights each cell, is it possible to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this functions to calculate dynamic height.
It return the hight of your textfiled's dynamic height based on your width.

```
-(CGFloat)getDynamicHeightOfLabelWithFont:(UIFont *)font withText:(NSString *)text withFrame:(CGRect)initialFrame
{
    UITextField *txtDummy = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:initialFrame];
    txtDummy.font = font;
    txtDummy.text = text;
    txtDummy.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    CGRect dummyFrame = initialFrame;

    dummyFrame.size = [txtDummy sizeThatFits:initialFrame.size];
    return dummyFrame.size.height;
}
```

You need to call that in 2 places

1. On `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
2. on `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`